# URL redirection in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, dns, redirect

I want redirect my domain url from example.com to example.net.

like;

http://example.com/u2C8i to http://example.net/u2C8i

http://example.com/* http://example.net/*

any any one access www.example.com so it will not redirect to example.net

Answer (score 0):

there is a few ways you could do it. First and probably the easiest is to create a DNS C-Name Reccord, but seeing as you tagged apache and .htaccess i'm going to guess you want to use mod_rewrite

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.net/$1 [L]
</ifModule>
```

you can eliminate the `RewriteCond` if you want everything that hits the web server folder to redirect, but this way it prevents redirect loops by only redirecting http://example.com

Comment: Thank, but site is hosted on shared server so I can't change in apache settings. Should this setting work in .htaccess?